# Making a control "global"

Tags: c#, wpf, global-variables

Is it possible to make a control global (or public) so that every window can access to that control which is located in a window. In other words, how can I access to that control within windows?

Comment: You probably shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your intention is, but my *educated guess* is that you want to update the visual state (UI) of a control instance (let's call it **C1**) within a window (let's call it **W1**) from other controls in other windows.

Assuming that's the case, the .NET framework already has everything you need: [Events and Delegates](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html).

When some data changes in a window/control that should trigger a change in **C1**, that window/control should fire an event that **C1** listens for and handles with a delegate. The UI update would happen in said delegate.

Comment: Intension is to make title of a window as the text of a selected listBox item in another window. Or, `this.Title = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();`

Comment: yep, that's pretty much a textbook case for events and delegates.

Comment: Yep - so define an event in the window containing listBox, with a custom EventArgs subclass containing the title, and subscribe to that event in the window you want to change the title bar of. If both windows were created using the same thread, that's probably all you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't really do something like that, but still...

Have you tried to set your control's `x:FieldModifier` attribute to `public`?